# Extruder motor wiggling

Tags: creality-ender-3

I made a successful print before this incident with my Ender 3 S1 running Klipper firmware. After that print, it started not extruding. Well, the motor started wiggling back and forth rapidly. After the prime line, it stopped completely. I thought it might be a problem with Klipper, so I switched back to stock firmware and used a different slicer too. But it is still there. I uploaded a video of it to YouTube:

https://youtube.com/shorts/q-ZLMg6NHng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced the cable to the extruder and the extruder motor.
Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your extruder stepper is not sequenced correctly. There are a number of possible causes of this.

Basically, the stepper has four (?) poles that must be sequenced in order to make it turn.  If you sequence them out of order, it will go back and forth instead of turning in one direction.

The causes for this could be any of:

- The poles are connected to the controller in the wrong order
- One or more of the drivers on the controller is burned out and is being effectively skipped
- The voltage on the controller is too low for the force being applied to the shaft output, causing the motor to jam and steps to be skipped

For an extruder, usually the output shaft is geared down, making the third possibility very unlikely.

Comment: Thank you. The motor has 4 Wires(I hope this information is useful). How do I check if the drivers are burned out?

Comment: Use a volt meter to check all four as you step it.  At the same time, you can verify the order is correct.